# Under the Chicago Manual of Style, does "year over year" need hyphenation when preceding a noun?

Tags: hyphenation, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated, cmos

In the sentence, `The company experienced strong year[-]over[-]year growth.`, how does the Chicago Manual of Style govern the hyphenation?

Part of me believes that it falls under the "phrases, adjectival" rules in § 7.89.2, but I'm not entirely sure. If it is governed by § 7.89.2 "phrases, adjectival" then my understanding is it would need to be hyphenated if preceding the noun like the example.

Comment: I can't get past the TOC on CMOS Online (not a subscriber), but is it possible that §7.85 **Compound modifiers before or after a noun** might be applicable? [FWIW, my inclination, without referring to any of the standard style guides, is to hyphenate.]

Comment: @JeffZeitlin ```When compound mod­ fiers (also called phrasal adjectives) such as high-profile or book-length precede a noun, hyphenation usually lends clarity. With the exception of proper nouns (such as United States) and compounds formed by an adverb ending in ly plus an adjective (see 7.86), it is never incorrect to hyphenate adjectival compounds before a noun.``` Seems like you are right! I suppose this is a a "compound modifier phrasal adjective?

Comment: I ask what difference do I provide the reader between "year-over-year growth" and year over year growth? Could they misread it as "(year over) year growth"?

Comment: I guess without hyphens you could misread it to think they were talking about a strong year rather than strong year-over-year growth, but I'm not sure how likely that is. Hyphenation doesn't seem necessary, even if it's allowed (some people seem to think it looks neater or is more logical).

Answer (score 1):

*The Chicago Manual of Style*, sixteenth edition (2010) addresses this issue (somewhat obliquely) in several separate entries. Here they are:

> **7.81 *Compound modifiers before or after a noun*.** When compound modifiers (also called phrasal adjectives) such as *open-mouthed* or *full-length* precede a noun, hyphenation usually lends clarity. With the exception of proper nouns (such as United States) and compounds formed by an adverb ending in -*ly* (see 7.82) it is never incorrect to hyphenate adjectival compounds before  noun. ...

and

> **7.83 *Multiple hyphens*.** Multiple hyphens are usually appropriate for such phrases as *an over-the-counter drug* or *a winner-take-all contest*. ...

and

> **7.85 *Hyphenation guide for compounds and words formed with prefixes*.** ...
>
> > [Category/specific term:] **phrases, adjectival** [Examples:] an over-the-counter drug | a matter-of-fact reply | an up-to-date solution | sold over the counter | her tone was matter of fact | hos equipment was up to date [Summary of rule:] Hyphenated before a noun; usually open after a noun.

These various guidelines indicate to me that *Chicago* would favor "year-over-year growth" but "growth year over year."